# Using Sprite Image on Google Earth

Tags: sprite, google-earth

Currently, I am loading a lot of placemarks on Google Earth on the website I created.  Each placemark corresponds on a single file from the server.  The placemarks are created one by one by the server coming from different images during initialization.

To ease the load of the server and the client,  I am planning to change the implementation I mentioned using sprite image using css.  Is this possible in Google Earth?  I can't find any information about this.  Maybe you can give some reference to do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ability to use Image Sprites for Placemark Icons](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=493)

I think you can do it something like:

```
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(me.placemark);
 me.point = ge.createPoint('');
 me.placemark.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(''));
 var IconStyle = me.placemark.getStyleSelector().getIconStyle();
 IconStyle.getColor().set(colour);
 IconStyle.getHotSpot().setXUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION); 
IconStyle.getHotSpot().setYUnits(ge.UNITS_FRACTION);
 IconStyle.getHotSpot().setX(0.5);
 IconStyle.getHotSpot().setY(0.5);
 me.setLoc(lat,lon);
```

IMHO: if there are thousands of images in the sprite it will load it as many times as the number of placemarks on the map.